# How to make file_reference in extbase extension in TYPO3 6.1 work?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I have set up a small extension with the extension builder containing a few fields, one of which is the internal_type: 'file_reference'.

```
'dokument' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:publikationen/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_publikationen_domain_model_publikation.dokument',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'file_reference',
        //'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_publikationen',
        'allowed' => '*',
        'disallowed' => 'php',
        'size' => 5,
    ),
),
```

The field appears in the backend, but the Element browser is unable to show any files to select:

[image]

If I remove the "bparams" parameter from the URL shown above, it is able to see the files that are there.

How can this be brought to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FAL fields require complicated configuration. To make that easier, there is a [function](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#ab95ff2f805d3ec462e869057339eee04) returning the TCA config for such a field.

Its usage for a field that allows only one file looks like this:

```
'dokument' => array(
    'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:publikationen/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_publikationen_domain_model_publikation.dokument',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'dokument',
        array(
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'minitems' => 1,
            'appearance' => array(
                'enabledControls' => array(
                    'dragdrop' => FALSE,
                    'localize' => FALSE,
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
),
```

A look into the [source code](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/_extension_management_utility_8php_source.html#l00446) of that function makes me not want to do that manually.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million! It works. How and where did you call that getFileFieldTCAConfig() function?

Comment: What do you mean? I simply call it in my TCA-config, which is located in `Configuration/Tca/<tablename>.php` (and referenced in `ext_tables.php`) - or did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry I just re-read the code and got it now (I didn't see the function in the snippet you posted!). All clear!

Comment: Here's a nice link for going further from here: http://keinerweiss.de/755-typo3-fal-in-einer-eigenen-extbasefluid-extension-einsetzen.html